# por que recebi a exceção "Chat socket closed unexpectedly"?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Recebi a exceção "`Chat socket closed unexpectedly`" neste script escrito em javascript:

```
const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
            'ws://'
            + window.location.host
            + '/ws/chat/'
            + roomName
            + '/'
        );

        chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (data.message + '\n');
        };

        chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
            console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
        };
```

Qual é o problema aqui ?? Eu não consigo resolver isso

Comment: A resposta para a sua pergunta está nela mesma, o chatSocket está fechando, por isso você está recebendo o erro, já que foi a saída que você mesmo colocou para imprimir. Tente printar o evento em si, e utilize o debugger do navegador para te auxiliar a entender o próprio código :D

Comment: assim como implemetou o `chatSocket.onclose`, implement o `chatSocket.onopen` para ver se conectou corretamente e veja se tem erros

Comment: Obrigado eu vou fazer isso